# Flying with toner within the EU

Tags: luggage, airlines, eu, ryanair

I will be soon flying with Ryanair from the UK and realized that I will be carrying a toner cartridge for a laser printer. Interestingly, in 2010 there was a foiled plan that involved [turning toner cartridges into bombs](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1324948/Al-Qaeda-ink-cartridge-bomb-jet-linked-mobile-phone-SIM-card.html). Soon after carrying a package with more than 500g [was banned](http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/printer-cartridges-banned-from-flights-as-war-on-terror-becomes-war-on-toner/), at least initially.

I have searched the airport website, the website of Ryanair and generally the 'net, but I cannot find anything about the current situation: it appears as though nobody cares about toner anymore. **Could someone clarify whether there are currently any restrictions on carrying toner cartridges?**

Comment: The Guardian in an article from 2010 reporting on this ban said _"Toner ink cartridges larger than 500g (17.6oz) will be forbidden on all flights leaving the UK from midnight tonight, and the ban is expected to remain in place for a month"_, so hopefully it really was just a temporary ban.

Answer (score 7):

According to the customer helpdesk of British Airways:

> Ink and toner cartridges weighing more than 500g will **NOT** be permitted as **hand baggage** on board our aircraft for all flights to or from the UK.

[Source](https://ukprepin.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3648/~/travelling-with-ink-and-toner-cartridges-to-and-from-the-uk). Noteworthy: the last update is timestamped at 23/05/2014.

Hence, checked baggage should be fine, as long as you don't go to the US:

> Ink and toner cartridges weighing more than 16 oz (453 g) will **NOT** be permitted as **hand baggage** or **checked baggage** on board our aircraft for all flights to or from the USA.

This applies to both ink and toner cartridges.

// edit: it appears the regulations may be carrier specific, as [KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/baggage_allowance/restricted_baggage.htm) explicitly lists printer cartridges under 'Chemical and toxic substances' that cannot be taken onto the aircraft (regardless of weight). Ryanair has a similar clause in its [prohibited items section](http://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/article8-prohibitedarticles/), but it doesn't explicitly mention printer cartridges. To be sure, I'd give Ryanair a call.